# Can VBA identify Python location without me specifying the path?

Tags: python, vba

I have a VBA code that calls a python program.

```
Sub Macro_bi()
    Dim Ret_Val
    Dim args as String
    args = """F:\Asset Management\Global Equity\Optimiser.py"""
    Ret_Val = Shell("C:\Users\CRay\anaconda3\python.exe" & " " & args, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

This works fine on my computer. However, I want everyone at work to be able to use this code. While all the other information will remain the same, everyone's local Python file path will change according to their username. I could manually go to everyone's computer and change it for them but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this where VBA can identify the local path on its own?

Comment: This is a lot more complicated than you might expect. What if they have multiple python versions installed? What if they prefer to use a virtual environment?

Comment: None of the people who will be using it have any previous programming experience so I'm pretty confident that they dont have Python installed and definitely don't have any preferences. The python program basically runs an optimization problem. The users only input data in an excel sheet and receive output back in an excel sheet. Is it possible for me to just identify their local username and input it into the string assuming everyone's location is in a similar format?